# How to write unordered set of vector of vector, namely unordered_set<vector<vector<int>> set?

Tags: c++, vector, set

I wanna have a set to store several graphs, and each graph has several dots, and each dot has its own coordinate. So here is my code:

```
unordered_set<vector<vector<int>> set;
vector<vector<int>> graph;
graph.push_back({1,1});
graph.push_back({2,2});
set.insert(graph);
```

Then the failure shows that set expect two arguments, but one provided.
I know for this problem, it's better to build a data structure to store dots, and graphs. But I just wanna know why this cannot be achieved by a set?

Comment: `unordered_set<vector<vector<int>> set;` -- You are missing a `>`.  Second, this will all be a moot point anyway, since `unordered_set` will not work with `vector<vector<int>>` unless you give `unordered_set` a hash function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would declare class or struct named: `Point` that contain two int variables and push every point to the graph (that now need to be `vector<Point>`) and then push the graph to your set (you can also declare class or struct named: `Graph` that contain vector)
and then your code should be :

```
unordered_set<Graph> set;
Graph graph;
graph.push_back(Point(1,1));
graph.push_back(Point(2,2));
set.insert(graph);
```

In addition, I don't think you need to use unorderd_set, I think `set` is enough and in this case, your code will be(without the classes):

```
std::set < std::vector<std::vector<int>>> set;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> graph;
graph.push_back({ 1, 1 });
graph.push_back({ 1, 1 });
set.insert(graph);
```

if you still want to use unorderd_ser I would look here (you need to give unordered_set a hash function.): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2280?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(C2280)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2019

they say that this is a deleted function, so this use of unorderd_set is iliglle check this link and get your answer for unorderd_set, I still offer you to use a regular set

hope I answered your question:)

Comment: "I don't think you need to use unorderd_set, I think set is enough" ? a `set` is more than an `unordered_set` not less

Comment: I mean you could use set and that's it

Answer (score 1):

Just to kindle your interest:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b11bd3b692248bde)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<>;
    std::list<Graph> set;

    Graph graph(3);
    add_edge(1, 1, graph);
    add_edge(2, 2, graph);

    set.push_back(graph);

    for (auto& g : set) {
        print_graph(g);
    }
}
```

Prints

```
0 --> 
1 --> 1 
2 --> 2
```

### Using in a Set

Sets mandate that the elements are "unique". So they'll have to know how to compare the elements:

- std::set needs a weak total order (basically `a < b`)
- std::unordered_set needs a hash + equality test (basically `std::hash<Graph>(a)` and `a == b`)

It would, however be uncommon for the unique-ness to actually matter. Do you instead want to look at graph iso-morphisms? What problem are you trying to solve?